# Remove parsed options and their values from sys.argv

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.5, optparse

I am trying to use optparse (to parse command line options to my script) and fileinput (to have the flexibility to provide data input via pipe or file).

```
import optparse, fileinput

parser = OptionParser()    
parser.add_option("-v", action="store_true", dest="verbose")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

for line in fileinput.input:
     process(line)
```

However fileinput tries to use the '-v' option as well as file name resulting in 'No such file or directory error'. So either I need to make fileinput args or remove the parsed options from sys.argv, however I don't know a elegant way of doing it. Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html):

> To specify an alternative list of filenames, pass it as the first argument to `input()`. A single file name is also allowed.

So you can just pass in the leftover `args` you get from `optparse`.

Comment: Aargh. Thanks a lot. Can't believe I missed that.